# Add a background to a Vertical Group

Tags: java, libgdx

How can one go about *adding a background* to a `LibGDX` `Vertical Group`?

I've checked the documentation for the class and it seems like there isn't a clean way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an [Image actor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Image.html) to a [Group](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Group.html), then add the Vertical Group to said Group. If you set the Group's dimensions to that of the Image actor, then set the Vertical Group to fill its parent, then you have effectively added a background to a Vertical Group.

Example:

```
Group g = new Group();

Image i = new Image(new Texture("pathtosomeimage.png"));

VerticalGroup vg = new VerticalGroup();

g.setSize(i.getWidth(), i.getHeight());
vg.setFillParent(true);

g.addActor(i);
g.addActor(vg);

//add stuff to the Vertical Group
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try swapping it out for a Table, which does have a setBackground() method, just put a row between every element.